# How to Decrease interval space in this Matrix - Vector Multiplication

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

Consider this following code :

```
\begin{matrix}
    & A & \\
    & \begin{bmatrix}
        a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1, n} \\
        a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2, n} \\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
        a_{n, 1} & a_{n, 2} & \cdots & a_{n, n}
\end{bmatrix} &\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
  & x & \\
 & \begin{bmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
\vdots \\
x_{n}
            \end{bmatrix} &\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
 & = & \\
\\
\\
&=&  \\
\\
\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}
  & b & \\
 & \begin{bmatrix}
b_{1} \\
b_{2} \\
\vdots \\
b_{n}
            \end{bmatrix} &\\
\end{matrix}
```

For which the following matrix vector output is obtained :
[image]

As you can see, the space interval between the matrix and the vector is unusually large and I can't seem to understand why, I wish there is a way to fix this in order to obtain the following desired form :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The large space comes because you are using an outer `matrix` with three columns and putting everything in the second one. The first and third column are thus empty but the inter-column space is there, resulting in the large spacing you observe. I suggest a couple of slightly different implementations based on a *single* outer `matrix` or `array`; right now the vertical alignment you observe is a happy coincidence.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

With \texttt{matrix}
\[
\begin{matrix}
A & x & = & b \\
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1, n} \\
    a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2, n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    a_{n, 1} & a_{n, 2} & \cdots & a_{n, n}
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
&
=
&
\begin{bmatrix}
    b_{1} \\
    b_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    b_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}
\]

With \texttt{array}
\[
\begin{array}{
              c
              @{} % suppress inter-column spacing; use e.g. @{\,} if you want more spacing
              c
              @{{}={}} % automatically put = with correct spacing
              c
             }
A & x & b \\
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1, n} \\
    a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2, n} \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    a_{n, 1} & a_{n, 2} & \cdots & a_{n, n}
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} \\
    x_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
&
\begin{bmatrix}
    b_{1} \\
    b_{2} \\
    \vdots \\
    b_{n}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `array` you can control the inter-column spacing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take note :)

Comment: With `@{}` instead of `@{\,}` it would be even better, I believe. +1 anyway.

Comment: @egreg I might agree and updated (mostly to add the description). However, the original `\,` was there to have the same result you get when typing the matrices alone.